# Why do pull requests appear when fetching

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Every time I `get fetch` from a GitHub repo, a bunch of pull requests are fetched from the remote:

```
/c/git/myProject>git fetch
From github.com:MyOrganization/myProject
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/1/head -> origin/pr/1
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/10/head -> origin/pr/10
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/11/head -> origin/pr/11
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/12/head -> origin/pr/12
 ...
```

To get rid of these, I use `git remote prune origin` or `git fetch --prune`, but the pull requests come back when I `git fetch` again. I found some references on the web that enable fetching pull requests locally (add `fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*` to `.git/config`), but I have not done this.

My coworker does not see this issue and his `~/.gitconfig` and `.git/config` look similar to mine. He uses git under cygwin, and I use git-bash that comes with GitHub for Windows (not the GUI), version 1.0.47.0.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub for Windows's "Git Portable" (a portable MsysGit installation) **sets the fetch refspec globally** to include pull requests; you can see that by doing a `git config --list` in git-bash.

You can undo this by removing the respective fetchspec, e.g.:

```
git config --system --unset remote.origin.fetch
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. It seems strange that `git config --system --unset remote.origin.fetch` shows `+refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*` after the doing the unset. Where does the setting get saved, if not in ~/.gitconfig?

Comment: it's in the system file, since it's a portable installation (because the "system" level file gets taken along, whereas a "user"/global level file wont). It's located in the Git Portable installation in the `etc` folder; where the installation is depends a bit on which Windows version you're using, but GH4W should be able to take you there (can't test it right now, but if you find the GH4W executable, you find Git Portable too)

Comment: There is an `/etc/gitconfig`. I'm guessing that is what gets updated by the `git config --system` command.

Comment: It seems that `git config -system...` setting does not persist nor modify `/etc/gitconfig`. I edited `/etc/gitconfig` and commented out the `[remote "origin"]` section, and that does seem to persist.